# Functions - different meanings in different languages?

Tags: java, function, alice, blockly

I am a very novice programmer, taking a course on the fundamentals of Java.
In Alice 3, a function is defined as: A Function computes and answers a question about an object, such as, “What is its width or height?"
I have used Blockly before and in Blockly, a function appears to be something else - more like a procedure. Can anyone help please?

Comment: java method is similar to a function. Don't really understand your question.

Comment: Basically, yes. Languages tend to have (usually small) differences in what they consider a function.

Comment: The terms "function", "procedure" or "method" are sometimes used interchangably, **BUT** strictly speaking, they have particular meanings (which may, to some extent, differ between programming languages). Maybe also have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155609/what-is-the-difference-between-a-method-and-a-function?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Each programming language has it's own vocabulary. Your general definition of "function" is adequate, though a function doesn't necessarily need to return anything meaningful; sometimes, we're more interested in the side effects of a function (for example, we're more concerned with what `printf` does than what it returns.)

Java uses the term "**method**" as the name for what some other programming languages call a **function**, or subroutine, or procedure. And there are a great many other differences than that. If all programming languages were the same, we'd have just one programming language.